# Is it secure to store JWT Refresh token in Firebase Auth Custom Claims?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an app with firebase and MongoDB. And I would like to add JWT Refresh token in Firebase Auth Custom Claims when a user is created using cloud function. Is it secure?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain, but I do not think that would be secure. You'd essentially be adding a refresh JWT to Firebase's auth JWT. Importantly, JWTs are encoded, but NOT encrypted. If your Firebase auth token were somehow hijacked, it could simply be decoded and the refresh JWT would be exposed. I'd think the exposed refresh token could then be used to retrieve a new legit token.